# How can I check for this specific Input?

Tags: loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

Enter Integer to add to the  tree (type 'stop') to exit >>8

How can I make my scanner to check for a string and integer and make a decision based on what is found?
If it is an integer I would continue being in this particular loop but if it is a string, how can I check for the exact exit condition (stop)? Without crashing the whole program?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
while(Scanner.hasNext()){
int a  = Scanner.nextInt(); //for integers  
String b = Scanner.nextString(); // strings
if(b.equals("stop") return 8;
}
```

Comment: I think that it will be waiting for two inputs, and I just need one at a time

Answer (score 0):

I think this might actually work:

```
  boolean flag = true;
            while(flag) {
                System.out.println("Enter Integer to add to three (type 'stop') to exit");
                String value = reader.next();
                if(value.equals("stop")){
                    flag =false;
                }
                else{
                Integer num = Integer.parseInt(value);
                tree.add(num);
                }
```